# how to create buffers and clip within pre-established areas, within the same process in r?

Tags: r, buffer, polygon, clip, intersect

I am evaluating the impact of mining in some areas and to see the scope of this impact I have generated buffers that go up to a certain distance. However, there are several areas that are spatially close, and these buffers end up reaching neighboring areas. And this has become a problem, because I am evaluating more than 300 areas and it is difficult to eliminate unwanted buffers through a visual review.
And I believe that there is some technique, but I couldn't find any.

- As in the example below, my impacted areas are in a `shapefile` and my study areas are in another `shapefile` :

  ```
  plot(study_area)
  plot(impacted_area, add=T)
  ```

[image]

The way I did it, I first generated the buffers using the gbuffer function.

```
library(rgeos)

#generate the buffers arround the impacted areas

my_buffer<- rgeos::gBuffer(impacted_area, width = 10000, byid = T)



###centroid remove 
my_buffer.er <- erase(my_buffer, impacted_area)
```

[image]

Later, to establish the limits, I used the intersect tool. This method works, but it can reach other neighboring areas.

```
 library(raster)
 study_area.bff <-raster::intersect(my_buffer.er, study_area)
```

- As there are more areas of study very close, the last two rings of my buffers reach the neighboring area, and this is something undesirable.

[image]

- this would be the expected clipping:
  [image]

One way to solve it would be to leave it on the shape, just the polygon with the limit of the area to be made the intersection, but I have several impacted areas (polygons), and in my view, it would be impossible to treat them separately.

-

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example that illustrates the problem

```
library(raster)
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(-60, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
p2 <- rbind(c(-45,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-45,0))
pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2)
xy <- SpatialPoints(rbind(cbind(-73.65, 1.75), cbind(-39.28, 2.35)))
xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(xy, data.frame(id=1:2))
b <- buffer(xy, 7000000, dissolve=FALSE)

plot(pols)
points(xy, cex=2, pch=20)
lines(b, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

It seems to me that you can fix this by intersecting the buffers with their corresponding polygons. You can do something along these lines

```
ptpol <- extract(pols, xy)

x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(b)) {
    x[[i]] <- intersect(b[i,], pols[ptpol$poly.ID[i], ])
}
x <- do.call(rbind, x)

lines(x, col="red", lwd=4)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't set a replicable example. In fact, the file in which I want to generate the buffers are also polygons, and when I tried to execute the suggested function: ptpol <- extract (pols, xy), it gave this error: it was not possible to find an inherited method for the function 'extract 'for signature' "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" ' .........

Comment: What you suggested above is basically what I need, however, the correct way for my case would be with polygons like this: p3 <- rbind (c (-90, -10), c (-90, -10), c (-100, -15), c (-130, -5), c (-150,10))
p4 <- rbind (c (-5.0), c (0.10), c (10.5), c (7, -15), c (-15.0)) - pols2 <- spPolygons (p3 , p4) but I don't know if there is another function that replaces the extraction function.

Comment: I do not understand how your polygons are different, or  what you mean with replacing the extraction function. It is probably best to edit your question, by adding some code where you use these polygons and show where you get stuck.